# Gradient and hessian after an affine transformation

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I know the definition of the Jacobian and hessian of $x$. However, I am confused how to find the jacobian and hessian of $z=Ax+b$. $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and b is a $m\times 1$ vector.

Hessian matrix of a vector-valued function is a third order tensor of the form:
$H(z)=[H(f1) H(f2) \dots H(fm)]$

Comment: What do you mean by the gradient of a vector valued function? That is nonstandard terminology.

Comment: changed it to jacobian @littleO

Comment: Now a follow-up question, what do you mean by the Hessian of a vector valued function?

Comment: In your definition of the Hessian, are you assuming that $f$ is a scalar-valued function?  If so, then this definition does not apply to your vector-valued function $z$.

Comment: @littleO I have edited my post.